# javascript in iframe won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a website with lots of code, so obviously something is wrong, but I can't post all the code here.  Here's the **exact code** I'm trying to use though.

Parent document...

```
<iframe name=combosIframe id=combosIframe src=getCombos.php style='position:absolute;left:300px;top:0px;width:275px;height:520px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;border:1px solid black'></iframe>
<form name=colorForm id=colorForm action=colorCombos.php method=post target=combosIframe>
   <input type=submit id=submitColors value=SubmitColors>
</form>
```

Inside the iframe, colorCombos.php page...

```
<script language=JavaScript>
   alert('load');
   function doSomething(){
      alert('hi');
   }
</script>

<form>
   <input type=button value=ClickMe onClick=doSomething()>
</form>
```

Scenario: I click the parent form button to load the new page into the iframe.

Problem: the JavaScript in the `colorCombos.php` page does not alert, either on page load, or when clicking the button.  If I view the page on its own it works fine.

Specs: php5, using Chrome browser.

Of note: there are no errors when I view the javascript console.  Also there is nothing else on the colorCombos.php page.  Both files are in the same directory.  Thanks for any help, I'm really stumped.

Comment: Do you have an issue with using quotes? `frames[0]` replacing the `0` with the correct frame number should give you access to the iframe contents as long as you have CORS access, which it looks like you do, since that's a relative path.

Comment: Quotes aren't needed for it to run.  I can try the frames[0] style of accessing it, but why would that matter?

Comment: Does `console.log()` show anything in the console (F12 -> Console)?

Comment: Try loading the getCombos.php page in a window on it's own and troubleshooting there. You may have a js error in your console that's blocking possibly.

Comment: How do you "load the new page into the iframe"?  Where's that code?

Comment: Instead of `language=JavaScript` try `type='text/javascript', in your `script` tag. Note: we don't see your `doSomething` function.

Comment: You would load a new page into an `iframe` with the window `frames` property, like: `frames[0].location = 'url.php';` . Otherwise, you can `document.getElementById('combosIframe').src = 'url.php';` .

Comment: jsve - thanks; console.log showed it is being called at least, but nothing else is happening.

Comment: everybody except jsve - please actually read what I posted!  Donovan, the getCombos.php page is not the page I'm working with; that was only the default page; I loaded colorCombos.php which has the script not working as shown in my post.  jfriend00, as my code shows, the parent page's form uses target=combosIframe.  PHPglue - you are mistaken, my doSomething function is in the second code snippet I posted; also the problem is not loading the page, it's getting the script to run on it, like when clicking the button as I said in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Not using quotes within HTML Attributes can have undesired effects. Try adding quotes around all the values of each HTML Attribute.

Example:

```
<input type="button" value="ClickMe" onClick="doSomething()"/>
```

Comment: No, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I started with a blank setup (which was working) copied the code from my site (which has lots of other code), bit by bit into the new document to see when the script stopped working.  I ended up copying EVERYTHING (literally ctrl+a) into the new document, and it worked fine.  I then renamed the new document to be the name of the old document, and it STOPPED working.  The old document (i.e. the parent document) is named rangeTool.php, not that I think that is relevant necessarily.

So I have a solution, but not an answer.  What in the world could cause one document to not work?  Something wrong on the server?  I deleted the old file off the server and loaded the new copy, but that didn't work as long as the name was rangeTool.php.  For example, I renamed it testcode.php and it worked fine.

I'm still interested in why/how this happened, but at least the pressure is off now that it's working for me.